Android 14 - java - partial access to photos how to apply it to wallpapers app
i have a wallpaper app
and when a user select picture to use then i need the external storage permission
until android 13 when user asked for permission he have the options to deny or accept
but since android 14 sdk level 34 a new option is added to make the user select what image files he want to grant access for.
now in my wallpaper app how i can let the user benefit from this option and how i can let him select the image he already picked from the app to get access.
and every time the user pick a new image he must be able to add it to the permission list.
how i can do that with code please in java
nothing i don't know from where should i start

What is the logic you have in place in your application? What did you try doing? Have you tried looking at the changes in Android 14 to permissions?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
